# Why are there 2 RAIDs in my /proc/mdstat?

Tags: raid, mdadm

My web hosting provider built up a bootable software RAID across all 4 drives. I have asked for a RAID 5. However when i type 'cat /proc/mdstat' i can see two RAIDs, a RAID 1 and a RAID 5. Why are there 2 RAIDs?

```
[root@x2 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0] sdc2[2] sdd2[3]
      511936 blocks super 1.0 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid5 sdb3[1] sdc3[2] sdd3[4] sda3[0]
      1463224320 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Comment: `/proc/mounts` would tell if/how they are used.

Comment: @Nominal Animal Thank you, thanks to you i have the full picture, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the RAID1 across the 4 drives is an array of mirrored boot partition to facilitate the recovery of the system if one drive fails.

The boot partition is copied on every drive to always have a clean available boot partition in case a drive literally dies.

```
[root@x2 ~]# cat /proc/mounts | grep md0
/dev/md0 /boot ext2 rw,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: I would have said that it's more because computers can't boot from any other RAID than RAID1, that is, they boot from the first disk that has a boot partition.